# Chrome slow down network speed selectively

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

In Google DevTools the Network tab has a section where you can set the type of network, for example, Fast 3G, Slow 3G, etc.  This applies to the entire site and helps you see how long the page will take to download for that connection.

However, is there a way to apply a network setting selectively to a resource ?

For example, I want to only slow down the download of my css file (keep the other resources to download fast), how can I do this with Chrome DevTools or an extension ?

Comment: Use a [separate program](https://alternativeto.net/software/netlimiter/).

Comment: @wOxxOm that’s a useless response in my case, my question was for Chrome

Comment: Bummer, you can't do that in Chrome so...

Comment: @wOxxOm bummer indeed